# git hub repository creation fails

Tags: git, repository, project, git-remote, creation

I tried following commands and failed:

```
> cd SecurityAlert/
> sudo apt-get install git
> git init
> git add .
> git config --global user.email "mail@gmail.com"
> git config --global user.name "user"
> git commit -m "First commit"
> git remote add origin https_link_github.com/user/SecurityAlert
> git push origin master
```

> To https_link_github.com/user/SecurityAlert
>     ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https_link_github.com/sandeepmhptr/SecurityAlert' hint: Updates were
>   rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>       hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>       hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>       hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

```
git pull
```

> There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please
>   specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for
>   details
>   git pull
>
> If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>   git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/ master

```
> git remote add -v

> git remote -v
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL you are putting in for the remote.

You used:

```
 > git remote add origin https_link_github.com/sandeepmhptr/SecurityAlert
```

This should be:

```
 > git remote add origin https://github.com/sandeepmhptr/SecurityAlert
```

Then, as long as you setup your Github repo correctly, you should be able to push okay - but the problems you had with pushing and the error message from that make it look like there are already commits on your remote repo (`origin`).

For pushing an existing repo to a new remote on Github, with the commands you are using, the Github Repo must have been initialized *without* adding a `README.md` or `.gitignore` file to it.  If you did add these, the easiest thing to do is delete the repo and create it again without adding any files, before pushing the first time.  In this case, make sure you remake it with exactly the same name, or update the URL.

Another option might be to force push, which basically will overwrite the remote repo with the history from your local repo.  If this is a brand-new repo and no one else has downloaded it yet, that's another option.

---

If the remote repo has some commits already that you want to keep, then you'll need to sync those into your local repo before you can push.  This can get very detailed, depending exactly what the differences are and how you want the merge history to come out.

Comment: the remote url is git remote add origin https://github.com/sandeepmhptr/SecurityAlert, I have written here git remote add origin https_link_github.com/sandeepmhptr/SecurityAlert because of some issues in this site, it was not allowing more than 2 urls

Comment: HI, I tried again with all these steps and it suceeded

Comment: Okay, good - looking a little closer it looks like the remote had already been initialized.  I added some more info to the answer to clarify.  I appreciate a checkmark or up vote if this did help, or answered your question.